# Redux calling action with "store.dispatch()" inside helper functions, updates the store but components has not re-rendered

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is my action:

```
export const changeKycModalShow = (scope, show) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'KYC_MODAL', payload: {
            scope,
            show
        }
    }) 
}
```

This is my reducer:

```
const KYC_INITIAL_STATE = {
    scope: '',
    show: false
}
const KYCPermissionModal = (state=KYC_INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'KYC_MODAL':
            return {scope: action.payload.scope, show: action.payload.show }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Here is how I call my helper:

```
switch (type) {
  case 'WITHDRAW':
     if(!permission(kycLevel, 'WITHDRAW_FIAT')) return
     break;
}
```

and here is my helper function

```
export const permission = (level, scope) => {
    let permissionAccess = false
    permissionScopes[level].forEach(targetScope => {
        if (targetScope === scope) permissionAccess = true
    })
    if(!permissionAccess) {
        store.dispatch(changeKycModalShow(scope, true))
        toast({ type: "error", message: authErrorMessages[scope]})
    } 
    return permissionAccess
}
```

and my redux dev tools shows the update as expected. but my component does not reflect on this change:

[image]

> Note that when I call this action in react component with **connect()** method, Process happens exactly the same and **it re-renders the DOM**. but not with **store.dispatch()**

Comment: How did you connect redux and your react component?